# Generator destruction when the break statement occurs

Tags: python, generator

I want to know when the Obj.**del()** method 
is going to be called.

```
def my_integers():
    Obj = ExitObj()
    i = 0
    while(1):
        yield i
        i += 1
def test_fun():
    for i in my_integers():
        if i > 3:
            break 
anything_function()
test_fun()
```

I did a test and Obj appeared to be deleted just after the break statement: before the anything_function() out the loop.

Can I rely on this and give some tasks that I want to be done when the loop is left to the __ del__ method of the object defined inside the generator?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I want to know when the `Obj.__del__()` method is going to be called.

You can't. It might never. Finalizers in Python (or in any environment with an automated garbage collector scheme, really) are not guaranteed to run at all, and should only be used for last-resort cleanup. If you want predictable lifetime management, use [`with` statement](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) and [context managers](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#typecontextmanager).

```
class Foo(object):
    def __enter__(self):
        print 'Entered with block'
    def __exit__(self, *exc_info):
        print 'Exited with block'
        return False

with Foo():
    pass
```

Answer (score 2):

In general you can't rely on destructor calling order. Destructors are called when the garbage collector reclaims the object. This can happen in indefinite future, or not happen at all if your program dies on an exception.

If you want a deterministric life cycle for your object, consider [creating it inside a `@contextmanager`-decorated function](http://docs.python.org/library/contextlib.html) and employing the `with` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what Python Language reference has to say bout [`object.__del__(self)`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#basic-customization),

> `x.__del__()` — ... is only called when x‘s reference count reaches zero. Some common situations that may prevent the reference count of an object from going to zero include: circular references between objects; a reference to the object on the stack frame of a function that caught an exception ...

So you should not rely on `__del__` for cleanup. Context manager (as Cat Plus Plus [mentions above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9026138/553995)), is the right choice.